# Retrofit 1.9 getting header

Tags: java, android, header, retrofit

Could someone give me an advice , how can I get just one headers . Because I'm getting all of header , I can't choose just one. This is my code:

```
LoginService loginService =
        RetrofitClient.createService(LoginService.class, userEmail, userPassword);
            loginService.basicLogin(new Callback<User>()

{
    @Override
    public void success (User user, Response response){

    List<retrofit.client.Header> tokens = response.getHeaders();

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "x-auth-token is" + xAuthToken));

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your are in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BetweenActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What about iterating over a `tokens` list to find the necessary element?

Comment: Thanks for advice ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the first token, you can use:

```
retrofit.client.Header firstToken;
if (tokens.size() > 0) {
    firstToken = tokens.get(0);
}
```

If you want to iterate through the tokens to find a specific one, you can use:

```
retrofit.client.Header token = null;
for (retrofit.client.Header tmpToken : tokens) {
    if (tmpToken.foo()) {
        token = tmpToken;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) I didnt know , that so simply is .

Comment: @BartoszBunzlau Can you please accept this answer if it solved your problem ;-)

Comment: I can't acctept this answer , because I have not enough reputation . When I get enough points I will accept! Thanks a lot